# Whats the best pattern to use by letting user choose between two (2) options after enabling a specific feature?

Tags: design, choices

I am creating this design pattern where user can enable or disable "Users Term and Condition", and by choosing in enabling it, user has to choose either using a URL hosted or a version created by the user. I am not really sure if the design below is the right or the best pattern.[image]

Comment: Um, I believe you did not understand what a design pattern actually is. It documents and names an accepted existing solution and puts it in context with other DPs.

Comment: As an alternative you could flatten the choice to (Don't show, Url, hosted).

Comment: If you feel you can confidently recognize an "empty" text field, "no terms and conditions" could be "just leave the text field empty if you don't want any T&C".

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me, I believe the terminology "we host a version for you" isn't great, perhaps:

[image: Example T&C's UI]